# Can anyone suggest a way to label a default phone number?

Tags: copywriting, labels

I couldn't come up with much more than simply putting (Default) next to the number, which I'm not too fond of.

Example:

[image]

Comment: In this context, what does a default phone number mean?

Comment: Your way is absolutely fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Primary

You could also use a visual identifier that could move based on which number was the *primary* number. This visual would need to also provide a textual explanation via a hover of the visual or other means.

Comment: thanks! i think primary is a better word to use here also.

Answer (score 0):

You could just ask them to provide a primary contact number and later in the form ask them if the number was a home ,office or mobile number by using radio buttons if you are interested in that information